# PHP inserting late through time blocks

Tags: php

hi im trying to make an time attendance based on a schedule and if not the code will block me , im thinking like this?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
$now = new DateTime();

$mysched = new DateTime("16:00");

// time sessions
// 7pm / 19:00
if ($now -> format ("H:i") > "19:00") {
// getting my late 
$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "19:15");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You're ".$diff->i." minutes late";
}
// 4pm / 16:00
else  if ($now -> format ("H:i") > "16:00") {

$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "16:15");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You're ".$diff->i." minutes late";
}
// 1pm :13:00
if ($now -> format ("H:i") > "13:00") {

$deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "13:15");
$diff = $now->diff($deadline);
echo "You're ".$diff->i." minutes late";
} 
else {
// block if im trying to log at 1pm 
}
// continue to inserting late to db....
```

so the problem is where do i add the block snippet to the code?

Answer (score 1):

> I think that you have to check with the UTC Time and your system time difference.The code for checking is below

```
<?php
$d = new DateTime();
$dtz = ($d->getOffset())/3600;//returnt he difference between utc and local time
timeToSeconds($dtz);

function timeToSeconds($dtz)
{
     $timeExploded = explode(':', $dtz);

     if (isset($timeExploded[2])) {
         return $timeExploded[0] * 3600 + $timeExploded[1] * 60 + $timeExploded[2];//ccalculate it into seconds

     }
      $val=$timeExploded[0] * 3600 + $timeExploded[1] * 60;//return the seonds
      echo "Actual difference between utc and timestamp: ". $dtz."<br />";//the time difference in hours
      echo "The total second is: ".$val."<br />";//time difference in seconds
        $hours = floor($val / 3600);
        $mins = floor($val / 60 % 60);
        $secs = floor($val % 60);
        $timeFormat = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);//convert seconds into H:i:s
        echo "After seconds to time ".$timeFormat."<br />";
        $dda=date("h:i:sa");//return the current timestamp
        echo "The current time is " . $dda."<br/>";
            $convert_current=strtotime($dda);//convert current timestamp
            $convert_utc=strtotime($timeFormat);//convert utc time
            echo "Convertion on current time: ".$convert_current."<br />";
            echo "Convertion on utc: ".$convert_utc."<br />";
                $minus=$convert_current-$convert_utc;//differentiate two time
                echo "The two difference in seconds: ".$minus."<br />";
                    $hours = floor($minus / 3600);
                    $mins = floor($minus / 60 % 60);
                    $secs = floor($minus % 60);
                    $correct = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);//converting again it into H:i:s
                    echo "UTC time: ".$correct."<br />";
}
?>
```

> In these you have to analyze with the default time zone you have been taken with the current time.